# Can't install Ubuntu 23.10.1 (freezed installation process)

Tags: system-installation, live-usb, freeze, copy, 23.10

Can't install Ubuntu 23.10.1. Installation process just freezed on "copying files". And I don't see any hdd activity at all (led is not blinking), so I think, that there is no any copying process.

1. Hash sum of the iso is correct.
2. Tried to make live usb via: Balena Etcher, Rufus, Ventoi.

Terminal screen here:
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LzwCi.jpg)